# Is there a way to find the historic parachain block PoV size?

Tags: pov

I know there is a maximum PoV block size limit for the parachain, it's now 5M. Is there a way to query the historical blocks PoV block size, via Polkadot Apps, the third party tool or the way to write one?

Comment: Good question, not sure if you can get the historic as is a constant defined in the polkadot repository: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/405fdeb214ef582c39e93ebbaf3dca536a29f2d7/primitives/src/v4/mod.rs#L365

Comment: I think this is an upper limit for the PoV block. Not the answer of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any existing mechanisms that easily allows for this. You would have to write an indexer yourself. It could sync a parachain from scratch and store the PoV size of each block.